# App loads images over wifi, but not 3g

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection

I am having a really weird issue. My app runs great on wifi, all of my images load from the net.

If i run the app for the very first time on 3G, images wont load.

If I switch to wifi, then switch back to 3G, images will load (new images load as well as they change).

I have no idea how to diagnose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be an issue with your service provider (cell-phone tower).  On 3g, can you load a website (say, apple.com) and the images show?

Answer (score 1):

Some suggestions

- Show some image loading code.
- Do you see anything in the console?
- Do the images load in MobileSafari when you are connected to 3G?
- If you use URLConnection to load the images. Do you handle or log errors?

This is hard to debug without more information.