# App loads data only over WiFi

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The App that I'm working on has to load data from a webserver.
If I open the App with connected WiFi, it loads the data very fast. But it don't loads the data if it is connected to EDGE.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.
Do I have to set something in the settings?

Greetings.

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3533557/app-loads-images-over-wifi-but-not-3g

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to do anything specifically to turn on connectivity when using EDGE or 3G.  It should just happen automatically.  Not to state the obvious, but EDGE is pretty slow (probably 20-40kbps tops usable in normal situations), and often performs even worse than the theoretical speeds provided by the technology.

That said, using a neat little preference pane called [Speed Limit](http://mschrag.github.com/), you can test your application in the simulator while *simulating* different bandwidth and latency constraints.  You can get a better idea of the way you should expect your app to perform under EDGE with low bandwidth and high latency (or any other network connection).  This will give you a better idea where your problem may lie and what to expect.

Comment: +1 for the great tool.  Speed Limit looks like it's quite handy.

Comment: Yes I know, and it was my fault. Later I have seen, that the complete iPhone has no connection.